# Use of 'Genius' in Nicholas Nickleby?

Tags: charles-dickens, nicholas-nickleby

In *Nicholas Nickleby*, people use the word "genius" to describe people they don't even know and in such a way that I do not believe it has the same meaning as we now use it with.

For instance, Mr Crowl says the following in Chapter 15:

> "and I'll tell you what's more-I think these two geniuses, whoever they are,..."

This is not the only time I have come across the word used strangely; however, I have also read it used as we use it now: describing someone of exceptional intellectual or creative power or other natural ability.

What is Dickens's meaning when he uses it in this other way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He appears to be using it in a sarcastic manner. He is saying that they are *so stupid*, that he'll call them geniuses. It's like when someone says:

"Washington DC is the capital of the United States?"
"Yes, you genius!"

You don't mean that they are *actually* super smart.

In this case,

> and I'll tell you what's more-I think these two geniuses, whoever they are,...

Could be saying the same thing as

> and I'll tell you what's more-I think these two idiots, whoever they are,..."

<sub>Disclaimer: I haven't read this book. This is based off of the question alone.</sub>

Comment: Charles Dickens is an Englishman, and we *are* very much inclined toward sarcasm as a part of everyday communication.

Answer (score 5):

In *Nicholas Nickleby*, Dickens uses the word *genius* thirty-three times, using five out of the ten major senses of the word in the *Oxford English Dictionary*. There must be a deliberate playfulness in employing the word in so many of its meanings. Here’s a survey of the various senses employed:

[Chapter 1](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/967/967-h/967-h.htm#link2HCH0001):

> Its boarding-houses are musical, and the notes of pianos and harps float in the evening time round the head of the mournful statue, the guardian **genius** of a little wilderness of shrubs, in the centre of the square.

This is sense 1a in the *OED*:

> 1.a. With reference to classical pagan belief: […] a guardian spirit similarly associated with a place, institution, thing, etc.

[Chapter 6](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/967/967-h/967-h.htm#link2HCH0006):

> ‘“What are you then?” asked the baron.
>
> ‘“A **genius**,” replied the figure.
>
> ‘“You don’t look much like one,” returned the baron scornfully.
>
> ‘“I am the **Genius** of Despair and Suicide,” said the apparition. “Now you know me.”

This is sense 4:

> 4. Chiefly with *of*. A quasi-mythological personification of something immaterial (as a virtue, custom, institution, etc.)

[Chapter 10](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/967/967-h/967-h.htm#link2HCH0010):

> ‘I think I have caught it now,’ said Miss La Creevy. ‘The very shade! This will be the sweetest portrait I have ever done, certainly.’
>
> ‘It will be your **genius** that makes it so, then, I am sure,’ replied Kate, smiling.

This is sense 7b:

> 7.b. Natural ability or capacity; quality of mind; attributes which suit a person for his or her peculiar work.

[Chapter 15](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/967/967-h/967-h.htm#link2HCH0018):

> ‘Well, so it is,’ rejoined Crowl; ‘and I’ll tell you what’s more—I think these two geniuses, whoever they are, have run away from somewhere.’

This is sense 8b:

> 8.b. An exceptionally intelligent or talented person, or one with exceptional skill in a particular area of art, science, etc.

but Crowl is being sarcastic: he actually suspects Nicholas and Newman of being escaped felons of some kind.

[Chapter 34](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/967/967-h/967-h.htm#link2HCH0034):

> ‘’Gad, Nickleby,’ said Mr. Mantalini, retreating towards his wife, ‘what a demneble fierce old evil **genius** you are!’

This is sense 2:

> 2. Either of two mutually opposed spirits imagined as accompanying a person throughout his or her life and exerting either a good or bad influence. Hence in extended use: a person who exerts a good or bad influence over another’s character, conduct, or fortunes.

Comment: +1 for some uncommonly interesting research!